# delete Gridview rows in C#2008

Tags: winforms, gridview

I want to delete rows in my gridview with the delete button on keyboard. What do I do?

Comment: Are you thinking the Delete key will delete the selected row, or any row?

Comment: I write a query whit Linq that delete that row on database.I just don't know how to do it whit Delete key

Comment: Is this a winforms or an ASP.Net app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write this code and delete my selected row .

```
        private void GridviewName_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
            {
               var delete = from del in Movie_List.Requests
                            where del.Movie_Name == GridviewName.Rows[GridviewName.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells["ColumnName"].Value.ToString()
                             select del;
                foreach (var Item in delete)
                {
                    Movie_List.Requests.DeleteOnSubmit(Item);
                    Movie_List.SubmitChanges();
                }
            }
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

try this

add a delegate to your gridView like this in the form.designer.cs file. Find the area where your gridview properties are being set and add this line at the bottom of the section.

```
this.gridview.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(gridview_KeyDown);
```

Then in your event handler do the following

```
void gridview_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //checks to see if the delete button has been clicked and if there are selected rows
        if (ModifierKeys == Keys.Delete && gridview.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        { 
                //perform delete
        }
    }
```

Comment: my friend my proble now is the row isn't delete when I press delete key and I know my code isn't correct.BECAUSE I don't know what I compare two value?